# Find the fastest time in which the object can break into unit sizes

Tags: optimization

There's the famous "Poison and Mouse" problem that uses the binary search approach to solve. Here's another optimisation problem.

Consider a bacteria that grows by 1 unit at night and splits into half its size (for even sizes) during the daytime if it wishes. During the daytime, it may split more than once as well- for example, a size 20 bacteria can either result into (10,10) bacteria during the daytime or it may also result into (10,5,5) or (5,5,5,5) as per its will. It may choose not to split during the day in fact, i.e, a size 20 bacteria may remain as a 20 sized bacteria throughout the day. For an n-sized bacteria, find the minimum time required to break into bacteria each of size 1 and find the total number of such unit bacteria at the end given that the n-sized bacteria starts in the morning of January 1.

Now, I am trying to minimise the value but how do I know if this is the minimum time required? How do we determine that? What I have thought is to let the n-sized bacteria can increase by 1 at night, if it's odd, else, divide into r bacteria of k size each, where k is odd (assuming n=k*2^r). Now, k

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a pure mathematical question, nothing related to programming.

Comment: Yes, it's algorithm based. So, I thought to post it here. Anyway, I'm removing it then. Thanks for informing!

Comment: Sure it can be solved by an algorithm, but since you haven't presented what you've tried nor any ideas or attempts, and it looks a lot like pure mathematical problems, I don't see how anyone can help with your code. Maybe adding some code you've tried, languages and what is the concrete problem you're facing will greatly help.

Comment: @Alejandro No, I'm not trying any code or something like that actually. I'm basically trying it mathematically tbh. Not trying to implement it.

Comment: [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) is definitely a better place for this question then. Algorithms, deduction and proofs are common there, but on Stack Overflow, we deal with code alone :P